# Select all elements with same class

Tags: jquery, css

I'm looking to highlight all elements on a page that have the same class, on hover.

Code I have so far:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('p.myclass').mouseover(function () {
    $(this).addClass('hover');
});
$('p.myclass').mouseout(function () {
    $(this).removeClass('hover');
});
});
```

[My brief example: JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/enigmarm/Y69fr/1/)

Currently it highlights only the element that I'm hovered over. But I would like it to highlight ALL elements that have the same class. How would this be done?
I am not particular whether it is done in CSS3 or Jquery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `mouseover` attaches an event handler to each element in your queried collection individually, the value of `this` inside the callback is the element that you are hovering over, and not the entire collection. Instead of `this`, use the selector.

```
$('p.myclass').mouseover(function () {
    $('p.myclass').addClass('hover');
});
```

Alternatively, you could cache your collection and refer to it for modest savings in terms of efficiency:

```
var coll = $('p.myclass');
coll.mouseover(function () {
    coll.addClass('hover');
});
```

Comment: Yes. `$(this)` only refers to one object at a time, not all of the classes.

Comment: Makes a lot of sense. Should've been obvious. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('p.myclass').mouseover(function () {
    $('p.myclass').addClass('hover');
});
$('p.myclass').mouseout(function () {
    $('p.myclass').removeClass('hover');
});
});
```